# Delta job on BigQuery misses records

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm facing an odd issue with a small delta job that I implemented on top of a streaming BigQuery table with Apache Beam.

I'm streaming data to a BigQuery table and every hour I run a job to copy any new records from that streaming table to a reconciled table. The delta is built on top of a CreateDatetime column I introduced on the streaming table. Once a record gets loaded to the streaming table, it gets the current UTC timestamp. So the delta naturally takes all records that have a newer CreateDatetime than last time up to the current time the Batch is running.

```
CreatedDatetime >= LastDeltaDate AND
CreatedDatetime < NowUTC
```

The logic for LastDeltaDate is as follows:

```
1. Start: LastDeltaDate = 2017-01-01 00:00:00
2. 1st Delta Run: 
- NowUTC = 2017-10-01 06:00:00
- LastDeltaDate = 2017-01-01 00:00:00
- at the end of the successful run LastDeltaDate = NowUTC
3. 2nd Delta Run:
- NowUTC = 2017-10-01 07:00:00
- LastDeltaDate = 2017-10-01 06:00:00
- at the end of the successful run LastDeltaDate = NowUTC
...
```

Now every other day I find records that are on my streaming table but never arrived on my reconciled table. When I check the timestamps I see they're far away from the batch run and when I check the Google Datflow log I can see that no records where returned for the query at that time but when I run the same query now, I get the records. Is there any way a streamed record could arrive super late in a query or is it possible that Apache Beam is processing a record but not writing it for a long time? I'm not applying any windowing strategy.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you determining the LastDeltaDate?

Comment: @BenChambers I've updated my question with a description of how the LastDeltaDate is determined.

Answer (score 1):

When performing streaming inserts, there is a delay in how quickly those rows are available for batch exports, as described in their documentation [data availability](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataavailability).

So, at time T2 you may have streamed a bunch of rows into BigQuery that are stored in the streaming buffer. You then run a batch job from time T1 to T2, but only see the rows up to T2-buffer. As a result, any rows that are in the buffer for each of the delta runs will be dropped.

You may need to make your selection of NowUTC aware of the streaming buffer, so that the *next* run process rows that were within the buffer.

Comment: Thanks. I remember reading somewhere that for a query the data in the streaming buffer would be available immediately but I guess a BigQueryIO doesn't count as a query? I guess a delta date won't work in BigQuery then as one can't rely on the timestamp (as unfortunately there's no default value for a BigQuery table). The only other option I see would be to always compare the streaming table with the reconciled table to copy any new records over. Did you have anything else in mind?

Comment: Instead of scanning up until now, you could attempt to scan only up what is fully in the table. It looks like this is at most 90 minutes. It also looks like if you issue a table.get call it will give you properties on the streaming buffer, including "streamingBuffer.oldestEntryTime" -- the timestamp of the oldest entry there. If you used that instead of NowUTC, you won't skip the rows currently in the buffer, and should scan them next time.

Comment: In Batch, BigQueryIO performs an export operation and then reads the files from GCS because this improves parallelism.

Comment: Unfortunately the "streamingBuffer.oldestEntryTime" doesn't help a lot because if I check this on my streaming table, the oldest entry is over 14 hours ago. On another (very rarely used table) it's even 3 days old, it doesn't seem to empty the buffer in the 90 minutes or is not updating the information?

Comment: This is even more confusing, I was monitoring the streaming buffer stats on my table just before and after I ran a Beam job using BigQueryIO. The buffer contained 11 records but the delta job copied them all to the next table. Coming back, this either means the statistics are wrong or BigQueryIO is doing a query after all?